# Python working with external file + regex substitution

Tags: python, html, regex, temporary, substitution

I have one loong script that that take some data.txt, and process it inside the script throught gnuplot and then print output as html web page.
The problem is that script need to be shorter and work with external files.
My question is how to make it work in this way:

1. read template_plot.gp (external file)
2. use regex to find *variable* and substitute it with my variables
3. save it as plot.gp
4. then read index.html
5. substitute *variables*
6. save index.html

I hope that my question is clear enough.
I do not know hot to read this temporary files, store them in string, substitute and then save them.
Someone told me to use something like "template.gp.in" "template.html.in" but I am new to this and canþt find any relevant information..

Thanks for help

edit: my script (using it on localhost now) it is not the best writed script but it is working :D

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
# enable debugging
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import subprocess
import os

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
# get data

data1 = form.getvalue("menu1")
data2 = form.getvalue("menu2")
choice = form.getvalue("menu0")

if (choice=="x"):
    plot = """
    plot \
    \
    '%s.txt' u 0:3 sm cs w l ls 1  t 'X-suradnice',\
    '%s.txt' u 0:3 sm cs w l ls 2  t 'X-suradnice'
    """%(data1,data2)
elif (choice=="y"):
    plot = """
    plot \
    \
    '%s.txt' u 0:4 sm cs w l ls 1  t 'y-suradnice',\
    '%s.txt' u 0:4 sm cs w l ls 2  t 'y-suradnice'
    """%(data1,data2)



#os.chmod("img", 0777)

from os import system, remove
system('gnuplot tmp.gp')

proc = subprocess.Popen(['gnuplot','-p'], 
                        shell=True,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )

proc.communicate("""
reset
set terminal pngcairo enhanced size 3000,500 font 'Arial,11' rounded; 
set output '/opt/lampp/htdocs/image.png'
set mytics 10
set title 'dáta ' font 'Arial,12'
set xlabel "Number of Samples (0.01 secs)"
set yrange ["-10":"10"]
set autoscale xfix
set encoding iso_8859_2

set grid
set samples 7000
set style line 1  lt 1 lw 0.5 lc rgb "red"
set style line 2  lt 1 lw 0.5 lc rgb "blue"
set style line 3  lt 1 lw 1 lc rgb "green"
set datafile separator "|"
%s

"""%(plot)) 


web = """

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id='wrapper'>
        <div id='header'>
                <header>

                <div class='right'>
                    <ul class='main_menu'>
                        <a href='index.html'><li>Home</li></a>
                        <a href='Graph.html'><li>Graph</li></a>
                        <a href='BC.html'><li>Bakalárska práca</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class='span'></div>
        </div>

        <div id='content'>
            <div class='content'>
                <div><h3>GRAF     '%s'    vs   '%s'</h3><br>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div style='height:520px;width:1000px;overflow:scroll;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;'>
                    <img src='http://localhost/image.png' alt='obrazok' />
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>

                <form action='/cgi-bin/test.py' method='post'>
                <p>choose data to plot</p>  
                    <select name = 'menu0'>
                        <option value='x'>X-axis</option>
                        <option value='y'>Y-axis</option>
                        <option value='z'>Y-axis</option>
                        <option value='all'>ALL axis</option>
                    </select>
                        <br>
                    <select name = 'menu1'>
                        <option value='8steps_acc'>8krokov (acc-human)</option>
                        <option value='8steps_gyro'>8krokov (gyro-human)</option>
                        <option value='8steps_gravity'>8krokov (gravity-human)</option>
                        <option value='9steps_acc'>9krokov (acc-human)</option>
                        <option value='9steps_gyro'>9krokov (gyro-human)</option>
                        <option value='9steps_gravity'>9krokov (gravity-human)</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <select name = 'menu2'>
                        <option selected value='null'>NULL</option>
                        <option value='8steps_acc'>8krokov (acc-human)</option>
                        <option value='8steps_gyro'>8krokov (gyro-human)</option>
                        <option value='8steps_gravity'>8krokov (gravity-human)</option>
                        <option value='9steps_acc'>9krokov (acc-human)</option>
                        <option value='9steps_gyro'>9krokov (gyro-human)</option>
                        <option value='9steps_gravity'>9krokov (gravity-human)</option>
                    </select>
                <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
                </form>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div id='footer'>
            <div
                class='footer_span'>
            </div>
            <div class='footer'>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




</body>
</html>
"""%(data1, data2)

print web

# set permissions back to read only
#os.chmod("img", 0755)
```

Comment: Edited... I added the script I need to rewrite.

Comment: Anything more specific you have a problem with than "all of it"? You've identified 6 more specific parts your program should have, and some of them (e.g. read an external file) are absolutely trivial. You should attempt to implement each part separately and then ask a specific question if you run into a problem.

Comment: OK i figure out how to open and read data and save them> Now I only need help with regex... How shoul I replace all "_bad_string_" in string with "my_string" ?